# D3 Force Layout with Geom Hull

Tags: d3.js

I have the following D3 Force Layout example that uses a simple data structure.

```
var data = {  
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Register", group: 1, "frequency": 1103},
    {"name":"Analyze Defect", group: 1, "frequency": 2206},
    {"name":"Repair (Complex)", group: 2, "frequency": 1447},
    {"name":"Test Repair", group: 2, "frequency": 3012},
    {"name":"Inform User", group: 2, "frequency": 1101},
    {"name":"Archive Repair", group: 2, "frequency": 999},
    {"name":"Repair (Simple)", group: 3, "frequency": 1568},
    {"name":"Restart Repair", group: 3, "frequency": 405}
  ],
  "arcs":[
        {
            "source": "Register",
            "target": "Analyze Defect",
            "frequency": 2206,
            "dependency": 0
        },
        {
            "source": "Register",
            "target": "Repair (Complex)",
            "frequency": 1447,
            "dependency": 0
        },
        {
            "source": "Register",
            "target": "Test Repair",
            "frequency": 3012,
            "dependency": 0
        },
        {
            "source": "Archive Repair",
            "target": "Inform User",
            "frequency": 1101,
            "dependency": 0
        },
        {
            "source": "Register",
            "target": "Archive Repair",
            "frequency": 999,
            "dependency": 0
        },
        {
            "source": "Register",
            "target": "Repair (Simple)",
            "frequency": 1568,
            "dependency": 0
        },
        {
            "source": "Register",
            "target": "Restart Repair",
            "frequency": 405,
            "dependency": 0
        }
  ]
};

var width = 800,
  height = 400;
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(100)
  .charge(-300)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select("#main-content").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);


  var nodes = data.nodes;
  var links = data.arcs;
  var pathtype = [];

  // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
      name: link.source
    });
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
      name: link.target
    });

    pathtype.push(link.dependency);

  });
  console.log(pathtype);
  force
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(pathtype)
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 25)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

  var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "link " + d.dependency;
    })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
      return "url(#" + d.dependency + ")";
    });

  var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .call(force.drag);

  var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
  function tick() {
    path.attr("d", linkArc);
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
  }

  function linkArc(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n6q0L5fu/8/

I need to add grouping functionality that uses the Hull functionality as shown in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/y4amnsbn/

What do I need to do to get the D3 example to make use of the group variable in the data example and use the hull functionality to group nodes?

**Edited**

I added the following code to the example but it still does not render the grouping:

```
    var groups = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.group;}).entries(nodes);

var groupPath = function(d) {
    var fakePoints = [];
    if (d.values.length > 2) {
      //[dx, dy] is the direction vector of the line
      var dx = d.values[1].x - d.values[0].x;
      var dy = d.values[1].y - d.values[0].y;

      //scale it to something very small
      dx *= 0.00001;
      dy *= 0.00001;

      //orthogonal directions to a 2D vector [dx, dy] are [dy, -dx] and [-dy, dx]
      //take the midpoint [mx, my] of the line and translate it in both directions
      var mx = (d.values[0].x + d.values[1].x) * 0.5;
      var my = (d.values[0].y + d.values[1].y) * 0.5;
      fakePoints = [
        [mx + dy, my - dx],
        [mx - dy, my + dx]
      ];
      //the two additional points will be sufficient for the convex hull algorithm

      //do not forget to append the fakePoints to the input data
      var point = "M" +
        d3.geom.hull(d.values.map(function(i) {
            return [i.x, i.y];
          })
          .concat(fakePoints))
        .join("L") + "Z";
      return point;
    }

    function tick() {
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(groups)
        .attr("d", groupPath)
        .enter().insert("path", "circle")
        .style("fill", "green")
        .style("stroke", "green")
        .style("stroke-width", 40)
        .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .style("opacity", .2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, here is an example.
Although it doesn't use your script entirely it provides the same data structure as yours so that you can reuse it in your code.

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

hullg = svg.append("g");

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-50)
    .size([width, height]);

  force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var groups = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.group }).entries(json.nodes);
  var groupPath = function(d) {
    return "M" + 
      d3.geom.hull(d.values.map(function(i) { return [i.x, i.y]; }))
        .join("L")
    + "Z";
  };
  var groupFill = function(d, i) { return 111 };

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

   hullg.selectAll("path")
    .data(groups)
      .attr("d", groupPath)
    .enter().insert("path", "circle")
      .style("fill", "#235")
      .style("stroke", "#235")
      .style("stroke-width", 40)
      .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .style("opacity", .2)
      .attr("d", groupPath);    
  });
```

The full source code for this example is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/loictalbot/3znqjosd/)